# Copy multiple columns and paste to another workbook in different order

Tags: vba, excel

Beginner question here.  Here is the code I've been working on

```
Private Sub Copy()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
(wb2 defined somewhere here)
With wb1.Sheets(1)
.Columns("A").Copy Destination = wb2.Sheets(2).Range("A1")
.Columns("B").Copy Destination = wb2.Sheets(2).Range("C1")
.Columns("C").Copy Destination = wb2.Sheets(2).Range("R1")
....

End With

End Sub
```

I was wondering if there are a shorter way of writing this?  Thanks.

EDIT:  It seems this code doesn't work. Is it because I can't use Copy method between two different workbooks?

Comment: It is possible to copy between different workbooks, you could try to change `wb2.Sheets(2).Range("A1")` to `wb2.Sheets(2).Columns("A")`. let me know if that works, then I can help you with making this code shorter.

Comment: @GoosvandenBekerom Yes you are right.  It worked when I changed it to .columns.  So how would I shorten this code?

Comment: you could make a function of it. let me put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a function/sub so you dont have to copy the full line for every row, also you should change `wb2.Sheets(2).Range("A1")` to `wb2.Sheets(2).Columns("A")`

The function/sub could look something like this:

```
sub CopyColumn (Og_col as String, New_col as string)
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    'set wb2 = some other workbook

    wb1.Sheets(1).Columns(Og_col).Copy Destination = wb2.Sheets(2).Columns(New_col)

End Sub
```

And then in your original code you change:

```
.Columns("A").Copy Destination = wb2.Sheets(2).Range("A1")
.Columns("B").Copy Destination = wb2.Sheets(2).Range("C1")
.Columns("C").Copy Destination = wb2.Sheets(2).Range("R1")
....
```

To:

```
Call CopyColumn("A", "A")
Call CopyColumn("B", "C")
Call CopyColumn("C", "R")
....
```

If you have a lot of columns this should be nicer code

Comment: Hey Goos I tried create a sub like you did but VBA kept returning Runtime error 424.  I was wondering if I'm calling a sub within the main sub, do my previously declared names/variable carry over? I did a debug print in my called sub and it doesn't seem to carry over.  How can I fix this?

Comment: wb1.Sheets(1).Columns(Og_col).Copy Destination = wb2.Sheets(2).Columns(New_col)    After I defined workbooks (namely wb1 and wb2), the sub seems worked fine.  However I'm a little uncomfortable that I have to define the workbook outside of the sub that contains the main flow.  Is there anyway for called subs to inherent information from the main sub?

Comment: oh that is because you didn't assign wb1 and wb2 in this sub, im sorry my fault, ill add this to the answer